# Spring email add attachment

Tags: java, spring, file, email

I am using Spring 3.2 and want to send an email with attachment. I have an array of bytes - how can I set it as an attachment?
I am doing like this:

```
bytes[] doc = docDao.findNextDoc().getBytes();
MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
try {
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    helper.addAttachment("doc", ???); // how can I set bytes here?
}
.... 
// other things
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `addAttachment()` with a [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataSource.html) or an [`InputStreamSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html). Both interfaces offer Byte array implementations (e.g. [`ByteArrayDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) or [`ByteArrayResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html)).

```
helper.addAttachment("doc", new ByteArrayResource(doc));
```

You also might reconsider polluting your memory with that byte array. Your DAO might support streams and so does `addAttachment()`.

Comment: Good suggestion about polluting memory with byte array. While an inputstream is supported, is there a way of sending a ZipOutputStream through the helper.addAttachment ?

Comment: Have a look at `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

You have **[ByteArrayResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html)**:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
....
helper.addAttachment("doc", new ByteArrayResource(docDao.findNextDoc().getBytes());
```